# Can Mysqli_query() calls be nested?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to implement the following code. What I want is to fetch the product id with column name `prod_id` from the table `cart_details` and then fetch the details for that product id with column name `prod_id` from the table `products`. But this code is not returning anything. Does this means that `mysqli_query()` calls cannot be nested?

```
<?php
$cart_id=$_POST['q'];
include "connection.php";
$cart_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$cart_id);
$query="select product_id from cart_details where cart_id = $cart_id";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $prod_id = $row['product_id'];
        $prodDetail = "Select  * from products where prod_id = $prod_id";
        $prodResult = mysqli_query($link,$prodDetails) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        if(!$prodResult){
            echo "There was an error in fetching the product with product ID ".$prod_id;
        }
        else{
            if(mysqli_num_rows($prodResult)==0)
            {
                echo "There is no item in this cart";
            }
            else{
                while($prod=mysqli_fetch_array($prodResult)){
                $prod_name=$prod['prod_name'];
                $prod_price=$prod['prod_price'];
                echo "<tr><td>".$prod_id."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$prod_name."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$prod_price."</td></tr>";
            }

            }
        }
    }

}
else{
    echo "Query Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: No, it does not mean that.  It means something is returning an error or no results.

Comment: While they can be nested like this, it's often the wrong way to write it. You should combine the two queries into a single join.

Comment: Your code refers to `$row['product_id']`, but according to the text of your question, the column is called `prod_id`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Your `else` statements are wrong. When `$result` or `$prodresult` is false, it means you got an error. If there was nothing in the cart, the query would succeed, but `mysqli_num_rows` would return 0.

Comment: @Mureinik No. `product_id` is a column in `cart_details` and `prod_id` is a column in `products`

Comment: My point is still valid. You print `There is no item in this cart` when the first query fails. But that's not what it means when a query fails.

Comment: @user3736335 Your question still seems to have incorrect column names. It says "fetch the prod_id from the table cart_details"

Comment: @Barmar That should not stop the query from returning anything. I can change that echo statement to say something like `Query Failed`, but that should not make any difference, as long as I am in development environment. I have edited my que statement for better clarity. Please recheck.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I tried that. Still no result, no errors.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: I never said it was causing your problem. It was just a comment. The fact that your code says that implies that you have a misunderstanding about how these functions work, I was trying to teach you.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 `error_reporting` won't report SQL errors. They're only shown with `echo mysqli_error($link)`.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Please make your last comment an answer. I changed `if($result)` to `if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)`. It returned the echo statement written in the `else()` clause. The `$cart_id` was not matching. Thanks

Comment: I edited my question to move `$cart_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$cart_id);` after include `"connection.php";` before you posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your this

`$query="select product_id from cart_details where cart_id = $cart_id";`

That how many rows you are returning.

You can achieve this by changing this line `if($result)`

To this

```
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)
```

**Note** `mysqli` does not automatically secure your applicattion. use `bindparam`